# Powering Down Arduino MKR1000

Tags: arduino-ide, sleep, mkr1000

The MKR1000 is still pretty new and I'm having a hard time getting good information on it. I'm using the Arduino IDE but don't find any functions to sleep the MKR1000. Most libraries I encounter are for AVR chips while the MKR1000 has an ARM chip. I want to put it to sleep until an external interrupt is called. I also use the millis() function, will this function be rendered useless if it goes to sleep?

In the data sheet for the ATSAMD21 it talks about the Wait for Interrupt instruction which puts the machine to sleep but it doesn't say how to call the instruction. How can I do this in the Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [rocketscream low power library](https://github.com/rocketscream/Low-Power/commit/9692ae155b0395c1a0676c063995cf06fe761203) looks like it supports the ATSAMD21.